# Cannot change enablement of isort extension because of its extension kind

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have disabled multiple extensions because I had some trouble with clangd and wasn't sure what is causing it.

I now wanted to re-enable the Python and Pylance extensions, but I am getting this error:

```
Cannot change enablement of isort extension because of its extension kind
```

I do not really see an "isort" extension in the list. I am not sure what could be causing this.

Comment: This could be a duplicate. Does this post solve it? [Issue with new isort extension installed as from VS-Code Update October 2022 (version 1.73)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74461394/issue-with-new-isort-extension-installed-as-from-vs-code-update-october-2022-ve)

Comment: @mosc9575 Yep, that's probably the cause. The problem for me is I cannot see the isort extension as it is hidden within the package, but I uninstalled the package entirelly and new install came with more recent isort.